# Is it possible to use my computer as a sort of a router?

Tags: networking, windows-10, routing, firewall

So I have made a sort of a firewall using WinDivert. It works just fine on my PC, but actually I'd like to achieve the same thing for my android phone. I'm too lazy to write a firewall app for my phone(from what I found by searching the net, it's totally possible - it is but a last resort). But suddenly I got an idea: Can I use my PC as a sort of a router or a proxy? e.g. when I request some site from my phone, the response from the site should be inspected on my PC, packets should be modified if needed and then the response is sent to my phone. Is this possible? I was able to achieve something like this by setting up a sort of a proxy using apache, but it only worked for HTTP and I didn't really enjoy overall quality of the pages(the HTML seemed kinda plain, like it had no CSS or whatsoever...). Is there a more elegant solution for this? I'm running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router certainly has a firewall that is much better than anything you
can install on the PC, since the router has no installed applications that
could be listening on open ports.

But if that doesn't satisfy your needs, Android has many firewall apps that
you can [find here](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=firewall&c=apps)
for almost every firewall product in existence.
No need to write your own.

Comment: yeah, sorry. perhaps I wasn't clear enough or simply mistaken. by a firewall I meant a program to modify packets that I and only I consider "malicious". It's not like I'm trying to protect myself from an attack or whatsoever. The packets that I'm modifying are sent by my ISP and they're not harmful, they're simply annoying. So there's no firewall in existence that could provide me with the function I implemented.

Comment: You could create a wireless hotspot on the PC, connect the phone to that, and run your program on the PC instead, but you are in for a lot of work.

Comment: Realistically, the router most likely has standard Linux iptables behind the scenes, and runs all sorts of junk such as HTTP server, SSH server, Telnet server, UPnP responder, FTP server, SMB media server, and in some cases even a manufacturer backdoor.

Comment: yeah would be nice if my router would allow me to freely use iptables. But it doesn't sadly. So I just have to create a wireless hotspot on my PC? Thanks, I'll try that. But I didn't get that second part of your message. "and run your program on the PC instead". Well, sorry if I wasn't clear enough, but I did write the program for my PC and am running it there.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. See [Use your PC as a mobile hotspot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027762/windows-use-your-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot).

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to work for me though. I'll try to see if I can fix that.

Comment: Nope, seems like I can't drop the annoying packets when using hotspot. So it won't do. I'll try to use the proxy approach now. Is there a way to use a proxy for HTTPS traffic on android? In the settings I could only find HTTP proxy. Do I need an app for that?